# Create a new instance of DB from a GUI - java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have to implement a simple GUI to connect to MongoDB client using java driver.

This is a picture of my GUI:

[image]

As you can see, one can choose a database and then press OK to connect. 

In `MongoDBClient` class there's a method (`getDatabasesName`) to detect all databases names that are present:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class MongoDBClient {

    private MongoClient client;

    public MongoDBClient() {

        try {
            this.client = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }

    public MongoClient getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getDatabasesName(){

        ArrayList<String> dbsName = new ArrayList<>();

        List<String> dbs = this.client.getDatabaseNames();
        Iterator<String> iterator = dbs.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            dbsName.add(iterator.next());
        }
        return dbsName;
    }


}
```

Then, in my `main` I create a new instance of MongoDBClient and I pass the arrayList of databases names to the `Window1` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MongoDBClient mongoClient = new MongoDBClient();
        ArrayList<String> dbName = mongoClient.getDatabasesName();  

        try {
            Window1 w1 = new Window1(dbName);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        }
    }
```

Finally, in my window one can choose a database from a group of buttons:

```
public void chooseDB(ArrayList<String> dbName) {

        dbButton= new JRadioButton[dbName.size()];
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

        int x = 5;

        for(int i = 0; i<dbName.size(); i++) {
            dbButton[i] = new JRadioButton(dbName.get(i));
            dbButton[i].setBounds(x, 28, 65, 15);
            dbButton[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.panel.add(dbButton[i]);

            x=x+100;

            group.add(dbButton[i]);
        }
}
```

After one presses OK, I want to create a new Instance of DB, but in main class not inside `window1` class.